# TypeScript class interface definition

Tags: types, typescript

I'm trying to create a definition file (`*.d.ts`) for a third party library.  This library has a base class that the user objects will end up being inherited from.  However, the library handles the construction of those objects and merges their own built-in methods with the user defined methods.  So, I can't just create an `interface` which the user class `implements` since the user class doesn't define the built-in methods from the base class.

TypeScript definitions `d.ts` file:

```
module otherlib {
    export interface Base {
        third_party_base_method(): string;
    }
}
```

User source:

```
// FAILS because MyClass doesn't define third_party_base_method()
class MyClass implements otherlib.Base {
    myfunc() {
        let str = this.third_party_base_method();
    }
}
```

A workaround I currently have is to create a TypeScript file (`*.ts`) which defines a `class` instead of an `interface` with all of the methods in the base type with empty bodies or return dummy values.  The user classes can then `extend` from this so the type checking works.  But, this seems really hacky and causes unnecessary and potentially dangerous prototype manipulation.   Is there a better way?

TypeScript `.ts` file to define third-party library base class:

```
module otherlib {
    export class Base {
        // Dummy stub definition that is never called
        third_party_base_method(): string { return "dummy"; }
    }
}
```

User source:

```
class MyClass extends otherlib.Base {
    myfunc() {
        // Proper type checking for calling the method that the
        // third party library adds to the object.
        let str = this.third_party_base_method();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I did in fact start to run into some trouble with extending with the empty stub functions.  So, my new workaround is just to create a stub to make casting easier...

TypeScript `d.ts` file to define third-party library base class:

```
module otherlib {
    export interface Base {
        third_party_base_method(): string;
    }
}
```

TypeScript `.ts` file for casting stub:

```
module otherlib_stub {
    export class Base {
        get base(): otherlib.Base { return <otherlib.Base><any>this; }
    }
}
```

User source:

```
class MyClass extends otherlib_stub.Base implements otherlib.Base {
    myfunc() {
        // Proper type checking for calling the method that the
        // third party library adds to the object.
        let str = this.base.third_party_base_method();
    }
}
```

Comment: For those who are curious, a particular library I am dealing with this is for Google's Polymer 0.9

Comment: Did you know about Definitely Typed? https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/polymer

Comment: The option for Polymer in there wasn't ported to 0.9.  Also, it doesn't really provide for creating a proper TypeScript class to pass to register that has a typing for dealing with the this context in user methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ambient declaration. This provides the type information, but doesn't generate any code in the JavaScript output:

```
declare module otherlib {
    export class Base {
        third_party_base_method(): string;
    }
}
```

You can put this in a file with the `.d.ts` extension, to make it clear that it isn't an implementation file.

**Update!**

It depends on exactly how the third party library works, but you could use an interface to wrap the external members and your local members into a single type.

The example below assumes you call a method that returns your extended class. You'll have to supply an example of how it actually works if you need help crafting the exact version of this.

```
declare module otherlib {
    export interface Base {
        third_party_base_method(): string;
    }

    export function externalCodeThatExtendsYourClass<T>(obj: any): T;
}

// You would need the class/interface pair for each class
class Example {
    yourMethod() {
        alert('All yours');
    }
}

// The interface wraps the class members and the externally added members into a single type
interface ExtendedExample extends Example, otherlib.Base { }


var example = otherlib.externalCodeThatExtendsYourClass<ExtendedExample>(new Example());

example.third_party_base_method();
example.yourMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work.  I can define the abstract class Base, yes.  But then when the user  class attempts to `implement Base` TypeScript complains that `third_party_base_method` is missing.

Comment: You may need to post another question, because it works here: http://bit.ly/1eanPkc

Comment: By using `extends otherlib.Base` it does indeed compile.  However, the problem with this is that when you actually create a MyClass object the compiled JavaScript then attempts to actually extend the  prototype based on otherlib.Base.  This has a runtime failure as the third party library isn't built to create objects this way.  It constructs and extends them itself with apparently some different convention that breaks with this.  I also tried making an ambient description with some arbitrary other unused namespace.  But, of course, `extends` also fails at runtime because it is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for the update!  This could help in some situations I'm sure.  However, the point of trying to get these typings is so that the user methods in MyClass or Example can access the third party methods with proper typing, not just users of the constructed object. This library doesn't actually have an explicit factory that returns objects to cast.  I did add an update to the question with a workaround that uses casting.